# Differentiate numerically a function with respect to another

Tags: derivatives, physics, chain-rule

I would appreciate some help to understand in a rigorous way a physics development.

I know the analytical expression of two quantities $S(V,T,\mu)$ and $N(V,T,\mu)$, and need to calculate $\left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial N}\right)_{V,\,T}$.

From chain rule, I know I should consider $$\left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial N}\right)_{V,\,T} = \left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial \mu}\right)_{V,\,T} \left(\frac{\partial \mu}{\partial N}\right)_{V,\,T}$$

but I'm not sure how to estimate the second term. I see no reasons why $\left(\frac{\partial \mu}{\partial N}\right)_{V,\,T}=\left(\frac{\partial N}{\partial \mu }\right)^{-1}_{V,\,T}$, so the only option  I see is to estimate $\mu$ as a function of $N$, and then differentiate the relation. But there is no analytical expression  for it, so I guess numerics is the only way ? Or am I missing something ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imagine you have an implicit relation between $x$ and $y$: 
$$f(x,y) = 0$$
Then the total differential of $f$ is exactly $0$. For your case let $y$ depend on $x$, clearly:
$$\frac{df(x,y(x))}{dx}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\frac{dy}{dx}=0$$
As a result, we can obtain the derivative of $y$ wrt. $x$ as follows:
$$\frac{dy}{dx} = -\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\bigg/\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} \tag{*}$$

The point is that you know how to compute analytically or numerically the derivatives involved in $(*)$

You have to compute $\frac{\partial S}{\partial N}$ and you know by the chain rule that:
$$\frac{\partial S(V,T,\mu(V,T,N))}{\partial N}=\frac{\partial S}{\partial \mu}\frac{\partial \mu}{\partial N}$$
Since you do not have an explicit relation like $\mu = \mu(V,T,N)$ you have to apply $(*)$ to the function $f(T,V,\mu,N)=N-N(T,V,\mu)=0$ with $x=N$ and $y=\mu$. Therefore you will have that the sought derivative is simply:
$$ \frac{\partial \mu}{\partial N}=-\frac{\partial f}{\partial N}\bigg/\frac{\partial f}{\partial \mu}=-1\bigg/\frac{\partial N}{\partial\mu}$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I don't quite see how to apply it in my case, though ? How does this help calculating $\frac{\partial \mu }{\partial N}$ ?

Comment: I've edited my post @Penangol

Answer (score 0):

Note that $V$ and $T$ are just constants in this calculation. Only $S$, $N$, and $\mu$ are variable, and behave in the usual way, as long as denominators do not become $0$.